# Good website with algorithms to solve

Tags: algorithm

I would like to find a websites with many algorithm exercises.
I knew one long ago but website address vanished from my computer, there was achievement system, thousands of algorithms, easier and harder etc.

Anybody know something?

Comment: Not a good question for SO ... but you might try [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the following :
For gaining some practice
http://www.spoj.com
https://uva.onlinejudge.org/

move to these for competitive coding
http://www.codechef.com
http://www.hackerrank.com

in-order to sharpen your algorithmic skills
http://www.codeforces.com
http://www.topcoder.com

Happy Coding ;)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I've looking for :)